# string variable and int variable together in mysql Update statement

Tags: python, mysql, variables

I have to enter string variable and int variable together in mysql Update statement using python

My code is as:

```
z=input("enter name:")
u=int(input("enter id"))
sn='update table1 set colname:"%s" where colid=%s'%z
cursor.execute(sn,(u,))
mydb.commit()
```

In the code I have given above `colname` should get string value means user name and `colid` should get int value means id in numbers. But after all these commands I get error:

> Error: Not enough arguments for string

I can't understand why I am getting error as for string variable we have to use `"%s"` in mysql statement and give its value to `%z` after statement as I have given and for int variable in `where` clause we have to give its variable in brackets as I have given above.

Note: When I replace `colid`'s `%s` with a constant integer and remove `(u,)` from `execute` statement then the code runs correctly without any errors.

Comment: You can use f-string as place holders. ```name = "world"``` then ```f"hello {name}"``` will give you ```"hello world"```

Comment: It should be `colname=`, not `colname:`

Comment: Oh sorry I had written it in here by mistake but on my computer I have typed '=' only . But then also it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

Put both variables in the `cursor.execute()` call.

```
sn='update table1 set colname = %s where colid=%s'
cursor.execute(sn, (z, u))
```